# Socket.io channel and message callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Hello guys i'm wondering how this really works:

```
subscriber.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    io.sockets.emit('message', {'channel': channel, 'message': message});
```

I really want to learn socket.io with your help, can you help me understand what is this line for? What `message` will e emitted? and what `channel` is that for? I want to understand this line of code please help me guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subscriber` variable you see isn't actually part of Socket.IO, it's a subscription to a Redis database. A subscribed Redis client will fire the `message` event when the instance it's subscribed to has new data. The callback provides `channel`, which is the channel the data was subscribed to, and then the actual data itself.

```
var subscriber = redis.createClient();
subscriber.on('message', function(channel, message) {
  io.sockets.emit('message', {
    'channel': channel,
    'message': message
  });
});
```

The channel and message variables don't specifically mean anything, they depend on what you, as the developer, is doing. Whatever channel you specify during publishing is whatever channel you will receive in. For example, if I create a publish client, I can publish messages with the `publish` method.

```
var publisher = redis.createClient();
publisher.publish(channel, message);
```

So a publication to channel `foo` will be received in channel `foo`:

```
var client1 = redis.createClient();
var client2 = redis.createClient();

client1.on('message', function(channel, message) {
  console.log('Message: "' + message + '" received from channel "' + channel + '");
});
client2.publish('foo', 'This is a test message.');
```

You will get in your console:

```
Message: "This is a test message." received from channel "foo"
```

Comment: what is the reason of executing this function multiple times?  subscriber.on('message', function(channel, message) {
  io.sockets.emit('message', {
    'channel': channel,
    'message': message
  });
});

Comment: The function passes the Redis event data to Socket.IO.

Comment: What should i do to execute this function for only one time?

Comment: Use `subscriber.once(...)`.